# Is there an emulator (VM) out there that can "restrict" processing power?

Tags: memory, cpu, speedtest

I've developed some JavaScript to test the ability of a computers processing by comparing "perfect" times (0 lag, doesn't exist) and "real" times (how long it *actually* took).

Now I need something to test it to see what's what.

**Is there something out there that restricts power so that I may emulate what kind of lag a slower system would use?**

i.e., *restrict to 2.2ghz processor with 4gb RAM*

Comment: Any recommendations besides Oracle's VirtualBox? Preferably something that's just a simulator and doesn't require major setups?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Oracle's VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) you can limit the VMs RAM, the amount of cores and the CPU time in percent.

Comment: I forgot all about this program. Haven't used it since Windows XP - gonna try it out! :)

Comment: Now I remember. You have to install OS's in partitions. If there are no other options I guess this will work. Wouldn't hurt to have it for cross-browser testing older software anyway.